Effect of row operations on the sign of eigenvalues/ positive definiteness of remaining submatrix
Suppose, we have a real, symmetric, positive definite matrix $M$.
We know that M is positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are positive.
My question is whether (Gaussian) eliminating variables alters the positive definiteness of the submatrix which is not row reduced yet. For instance, if we have $Mx = b$: $$ \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\ 
x_3 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-1 \\ 
6 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
$$
Suppose, we only apply row operations where we add a (nonzero) multiple of one row to another row.
To start the elimination, we add $0.5$ times the first row to the second row. This yields the system:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 3/2 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\ 
x_3 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-1 \\ 
6 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
$$
In this case, my question translates to determining whether the submatrix $$S = \begin{bmatrix}
3/2 & -1\\
-1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$ remains positive definite or not. In this case it does, as all its eigenvalues remain positive.
Are there any theorems that guarantee the positive definiteness of such submatrices? Or is there a counterexample that can be constructed?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You should try miroring the row operations with equivalent column operations, then you can infer the result with Sylvester's Law of Inertia.
